# How would I use JSoup to display a Document on a JEditorPane or similar

Tags: java, jsoup, document

Would I be able to display a JSoup `org.jsoup.nodes.Document` in a window. What I'm doing is taking HTML code from `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();` and I want to display `doc` in a window. How would I go about doing this? Also if it is possible, would I be able to style it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSoup` is the wrong API for this purpose. It is used to parse HTML content into its document elements.

`JEditorPane` has a `setPage` method for setting content which will also give you the styling for the page:

```
editorPane.setPage(new URL("http://www.mysite.com"));
```

Comment: OH! That makes it WAAAY easier! Thanks!